# Detect if first and last child of a div has a class change through JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am hoping to hide/show a div based on the class change in the first and last child.

```
<div class="owl-stage">
    <div class="owl-item active">
        <img src="imagge.png" alt="alt text">
    </div>
    <div class="owl-item">
        <img src="imagge2.png" alt="alt text">
    </div>
    <div class="owl-item">
        <img src="imagge3.png" alt="alt text">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

Hence, if the first child has the class active in it, the `".buttons .left"` should hide, otherwise the `"right"` should hide.

The `active` ofcourse moves recurrently on the site and I am hoping I could run this function whenever the class `active` is changed.

Here is what I tried:-

```
jQuery('div.owl-item').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
  if(jQuery('div.owl-item:first').hasClass("active")) {//Hide Left or Right}
});
```

Comment: it seems that it can be done with Mutation Observers, but i haven't looked at this yet, so i can just suggest it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Owl Carousel has a built in [events API](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html). The best solution would be to leverage this and hook into the `onChanged` callback. And use the returned `event` data to calculate the `first` and `last` options. As per the docs (emphasis added):

> // Provided by the core
>       var element   = event.target;         // DOM element, in this example .owl-carousel
>       var name      = event.type;           // Name of the event, in this example dragged
>       var namespace = event.namespace;      // Namespace of the event, in this example owl.carousel
>       **var items     = event.item.count;**     // Number of items
>       **var item      = event.item.index;**     // Position of the current item
>       // Provided by the navigation plugin
>       var pages     = event.page.count;     // Number of pages
>       var page      = event.page.index;     // Position of the current page
>       var size      = event.page.size;      // Number of items per page

So when setting up your carousel youd use something like

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    onChanged: onChangedCallback
});
function onChangedCallback(event) {
    if(event.item.index === 0){
        // is on the "first" item
        $('.buttons .left').hide();
        $('.buttons .right').show();
    }else if(event.item.index === event.item.count - 1){
        // is on the "last" item
        $('.buttons .left').show();
        $('.buttons .right').hide();
    }else{
        $('.buttons .left').show();
        $('.buttons .right').show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've added some comments along the code.

```js
 $(function() {
   $('.buttons .left').hide(); //initial run
   $('div.owl-stage').on('triggerClassChange', function() {
     if ($(this).find('div.owl-item').first().hasClass('active')) {
       $('.buttons .left').hide();
     } else {
       $('.buttons .left').show();
     }
     if ($(this).find('div.owl-item').last().hasClass('active')) {
       $('.buttons .right').hide();
     } else {
       $('.buttons .right').show();
     }

   });

   $('.buttons .right').click(function() {
     var ref = $('div.owl-stage').find('div.owl-item.active').get(0); // current item that has active class
     var refNext = $(ref).next(); //reference for the next item adjacent to the current .active item
     if (refNext.get(0) != undefined) { //make sure there is a item available
       $(refNext).addClass('active'); //add class to the next item
       $(ref).removeClass('active').trigger('triggerClassChange'); //remove class on current and trigger our custom event
     }

   });

   $('.buttons .left').click(function() {
     var ref = $('div.owl-stage').find('div.owl-item.active').get(0); // current item that has active class
     var refPrev = $(ref).prev(); //reference for the next item adjacent to the current .active item
     if (refPrev.get(0) != undefined) { //make sure there is a item available
       $(refPrev).addClass('active'); //add class to the next item
       $(ref).removeClass('active').trigger('triggerClassChange'); // remove class on current and trigger our custom event
     }
   });

 })
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
.right {
  display: inline-block;
}
.left {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="owl-stage">
  <div id='1' class="owl-item active">
    <img src="imagge.png" alt="alt text">
  </div>
  <div id='10' class="owl-item">
    <img src="imagge2.png" alt="alt text">
  </div>
  <div id='2' class="owl-item">
    <img src="imagge2.png" alt="alt text">
  </div>
  <div id='3' class="owl-item">
    <img src="imagge3.png" alt="alt text">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Browser: Chrome 55

[Interface MutationObserver](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#mutation-observers)

```js
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutationRecord) {
  var target = mutationRecord[0].target;
  var id = target.id;
  var className = target.className;

  if (id === "owl1" && className.indexOf("active") > -1) {
    //Hide Left or Right
  } else if (id === "owl3" && className.indexOf("active") > -1) {
    //Hide Left or Right
  } else {
    //Hide Left or Right
  }
});

observer.observe(document.querySelector("div.owl-item"), {
  attributes: true,
  attributeFilter: ["class"]
});

document.querySelector("#owl1").className += " active";
```

```html
<div class="owl-stage">
  <div class="owl-item" id="owl1">
    <img src="imagge.png" alt="alt text">
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item" id="owl2">
    <img src="imagge2.png" alt="alt text">
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item" id="owl3">
    <img src="imagge3.png" alt="alt text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not try custom events. May be this url will be of some help. http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/creating-custom-events-with-jquery.html